# Move code out of a long controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, refactoring, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm refactoring a rails app that has a very bloated create action (more than 200 lines of code).

I'd like to make it much simpler to maintain and move some code out of it. This code doesn't belong to the model, since the app is just grabbing a file and processing it.
It is just a lot of ruby code that processes strings.

I would be just happy to create a class called "Processing" and move it in a separate file (maybe in lib/?), but I'm not sure this is the preferred way.

Should I instead package a gem to include in the project. I have no experience in this field, but it might be a cleaner approach.

Comment: Instead of writing a whole gem for it, you could drop it into a seperate module / class in your `/lib` directory.

Comment: @nTraum, is it normal that I have to restart the rails server evrytime I modify the file in /lib?

Comment: Yes, for a solution check: http://hemju.com/index.php/2011/02/rails-3-quicktip-auto-reload-lib-folders-in-development-mode/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the nature of that string processing code put it into a **Module** or **Class** (in both cases this should go somewhere under /lib). I would use a gem really only if you think that other projects might benefit from that code. Gems with less than 200 lines are rather uncommon.

Comment: How would you decide between module and class?

Comment: @TopperH There are stackoverflow Q/As and lots of forum threads/philosophies about that. It depends really. My careful advise for you is to put it in a Module for now, except you would profit from some state that is ugly to look at when handled in your methods.